# array of names = get correct file

Tags: php, arrays, include

I'm trying to write a list of files and drop them into an array.
Have to change the content on a page calling external contents.

I've found this little piece of code and trying to make it work.
[LINK](http://woork.blogspot.com/2007/10/load-page-using-url-variables-and-php.html) (last comment)

```
$all_pages=array("main","page_two","page_three");    
$page = $_GET['page'];    
if( isset($page) and array_key_exists("$page", $all_pages) ) // added a missing ')'
{
include('subfolder/folder/'.$_GET['$page'].'.html');
}
```

well, this does not work.
Just can't get to the right file. (the content shows always empty).

I (try to) call the files like:

```
<ul>    
   <li><a href="template.php?main">Main content</a></li>
   <li><a href="template.php?page_two">Second content</a></li>
   <li><a href="template.php?page_three">Third content</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: should be "template.php?page=main" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use `in_array()` to test for allowed values. `array_key_exists` would require the page names to be array keys.

Secondly, `$_GET["page"]` will be empty, as you didn't have a get parameter of that name. You must adapt your links:

```
   <li><a href="template.php?page=main">Main content</a></li>
   <li><a href="template.php?page=page_two">Second content</a></li>
   <li><a href="template.php?page=page_three">Third content</a></li>
```

(Or otherwise use `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`. But *you* probably don't want to do that.)

Your third problem was using:

```
include('subfolder/folder/'.$_GET['$page'].'.html');
                            ^^^    ^^^
```

You should have used just the `$page` variable here, which you already read from `$_GET`. Using that name as key again would not work. And you additionally used it ín single quotes (doubly wrong, but luckily without effect).

So correct would be:

```
$all_pages = array("main", "page_two", "page_three");    
$page = $_GET['page'];
if ( in_array($page, $all_pages) )
{
    include('subfolder/folder/'.$page.'.html');
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I think I should add an `else` to point to the main content, right? 'cause initially it won't load the 'main' content BTW this works great!

Comment: Yes, the default include belongs into the `else` block here.

Answer (score 1):

Change `array_key_exists` to `in_array`. Also, the variable $page could be set but be empty, check to make sure it's not empty with `if( !empty( $page) && ...` etc.

Comment: Thank you! Appretiate your help! +1!